# Interchange of indices

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, tensor-calculus

How to get the second equation, please? My result is wrong - I still have $(N-1)$. Thank you

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
(N-1)B_{\sigma\nu}&+B_{\nu\sigma}=g_{\sigma\nu}B_{\mu}^{\ \ \mu}\\
-(N-1)B_{\nu\sigma}&-B_{\sigma\nu}=-g_{\nu\sigma}B_{\mu}^{\ \ \mu}\\
\hline
(N-2)B_{\sigma\nu}&-(N-2)B_{\nu\sigma}=g_{\sigma\nu}B_{\mu}^{\ \ \mu}-g_{\nu\sigma}B_{\mu}^{\ \ \mu}\\
(N-2)B_{\sigma\nu}&-(N-2)B_{\nu\sigma}=0\\&(\because g_{\sigma\nu}\text{ is symmetric})
\end{align*}